# No profiles for 'XXXXX.onesignal' were found

Tags: xcode, flutter, onesignal

i'm having error when i'm run flutter building ios, this is the error message:

```
error: No profiles for 'xxxx.onesignal' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching
'XXXX.onesignal'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass
-allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' from project 'Runner')
warning: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: XXXXX" for "Runner" contains entitlements that aren't in the
entitlements file: com.apple.developer.usernotifications.time-sensitive, com.apple.developer.fileprovider.testing-mode, and
com.apple.developer.usernotifications.communication. To use these entitlements, add them to your entitlements file. Otherwise, remove
unused entitlements from your provisioning profile. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

i tried all solutions available until i run on another issue wile following steps to reproduce to register onesignal id on apple developer acount.

[image: This is the error when i try to register the build id.]

but i don't have it registered on my acount. What can i do to fix it

Answer (score 0):

1.first you can genrate your app certificate for provisional and development using following url.[here](https://developer.apple.com/)

Comment: i've already have one

Comment: so you can select automatically sign in certificate.

Answer (score 0):

i've resolved part of the error by following this url [here](https://www.ottorinobruni.com/how-to-fix-error-profile-doesnt-match-the-entitlements-files-values-for-the-application-identifier-and-keychain-access-groups-entitlements/).

wich leave me with this error

```
 error: No profiles for 'XXXX.onesignal' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching
'XXXX.onesignal'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass
-allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' from project 'Runner')
```